# Why does Github put my commits under another account?

Tags: git, github

I always push my commits as a account stsushi, but my commits always end up on github under another account. Anyone understand why?

Comment: did you have multiple accounts ?

Comment: i think you have multiple account BPS-1 is you another account and you have config  your email of that account in  you system just change your email in system its store in .gitconfig file you git config command to update your email .

Comment: if it helps please let me know i will post on answer.

Comment: What is result of `git log` in your local repo?

Comment: Thanks, I was using a school computer, and didn't realize i had a git config global user stored in my vm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+commit+different+account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two accounts on GitHub

1. [Stsushi](https://github.com/stsushi)
2. [BPS-1](https://github.com/BPS-1)

Right now git configured with email of BPS-1 in you system.

just configure your desire email 
**Like** 
`git config --global user.email "email@example.com"`

Hope it will help you. Happy Coding..!